# Page not refreshing partially

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.net 3.5 and Ajax toolkit is 2.0. Following is my code and my page is not refreshing partially. Is there any way to debug where is the issue?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_country" runat="server" Style="width: 100%;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_country_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="div_Port_ddl" runat="server" style="width: 100%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_port" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="100%" onchange="SetPortId(this);"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_port_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_country" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what the example is doing, how it should be working, and specifically what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the UpdateMode of your Update Panel to Conditional.  Then in the SelectIndexChanged of "ddl_Country" you could call UpdatePanel1.Update().

Answer (score 1):

You must set the UpdateMode attribute to Conditional for the triggers to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Could have something to do with: `onchange="SetPortId(this);"`. Not sure, but try returning true in or after that function call:

```
onchange="SetPortId(this);return true;"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Enabling Partial-Page Rendering Support

You enable or disable partial-page rendering for a page by setting the EnablePartialRendering property of the ScriptManager control. You can also specify whether partial-page rendering is supported for a page by setting the SupportsPartialRendering property of the ScriptManager control. If you do not set the SupportsPartialRendering property and if the EnablePartialRendering set the property is true (which is the default), the capabilities of the browser are used determine whether partial-page rendering is supported If partial-page rendering is not enabled for a page, if it has been disabled, or if s not supported in a browser, the page uses fallback behavior. Actions that is not supported in a browser, the page uses fallback behavior. Actions that ordinarily would perform an asynchronous postback instead perform a synchronous postback and update the whole page. Any UpdatePanel controls o the page are ignored, and their contents are rendered as if they were not insid an UpdatePanel control.

I think it is not required as I didn't required it in one of my project for same purpose but also, try using UpdateMode="Conditional".

Also check this [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx) and for detailed information for working with [partial rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976.aspx)